# How to fix "DOMException" error in Web Bluetooth API?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, web-bluetooth, fido

I'm setting up a Bluetooth LE GATT Server in Android, and want to use Web Bluetooth API in Chrome as a GATT client to check if it properly works. Actually, this is my first step to build a FIDO Authenticator in Android later on.

Firstly, I tried to set my service's uuid is `0000fffd-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` in my Android app. Something like this:

```java
// start gatt server

bluetoothGattServer = bluetoothManager.openGattServer(this, callback);
bluetoothGattServer.addService(
new BluetoothGattService(UUID.fromString("0000fffd-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"),
BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY));

// start advertising
// ...
```

Then, I executed the following Javascript code in Chrome to check whether the connection can be established.

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ 
filters: [{ services: ['0000fffd-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'] }] })
.then(device => { console.log(device); })
.catch(error => { console.log(error); });
```

However, I only got the exception as below

```
DOMException
```

When I changed the uuid to another one such as `62893031-5e68-4a71-94e4-01fb81f16818` in my Android code, then it worked! (I mean it was able to connect to my phone and I could see my device info in Chrome's console)

I didn't know what exactly the problem. What was the problem with my former uuid? How can I debug it to know the root cause?

Thank you for checking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
console.log(error.messsage);
```

in stead of

```
console.log(error);
```

You will see

> requestDevice() called with a filter containing a blocklisted UUID.
>   https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#attacks-on-devices

Check it out to see the security reason.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! You're right! Now, I could understand why my mentioned uuid was a problem. I found it in the GATT blocklist [here](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/registries/blob/master/gatt_blocklist.txt)